# Only month view in fullcalendar (remove/Hide "Day" and "Weeks" view)

Tags: fullcalendar

My fullcalendar has - "Month|Week|Day" view , I want to remove or hide the "Week" and "Day" views as we have been using only "Month" View.

Can you please tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

When you start fullcalendar, don't include agendayDay and agendaWeek.  Something like

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month'
    }
});
```

Update:
To get rid of the month button:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next',
        center: 'title',
        right: ''
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, It works. Now only "Month" tab is appear. Is it possible to remove that "Month" tab too as it is already appear this is month view so no need for such disabled tab. ?

Comment: @tubaguy50035 it's working but if I need to show only month and week view then how can I do it ???? Please provider your suggestion

Answer (score -2):

right : false is working.

```
 $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next ',
                center: 'title',
                right: false,
            },

    });
```