# Add a custom button to FullCalendar but only for a specific view

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

Using [FullCalendar](https://fullcalendar.io/) v5 you can add custom buttons [as documented here](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v5/customButtons).

Is it possible to only show the custom button if the user is on a specific view e.g. [month view](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v5/month-view)?

e.g. How can I get `myCustomButton` from below only appear on `dayGridMonth` view?

```
var calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
  customButtons: {
    myCustomButton: {
      text: 'custom!',
      click: function() {
        alert('clicked the custom button!');
      }
    }
  },
  headerToolbar: {
    left: 'prev,next today myCustomButton',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
  }
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use Custom button only for month view in JavaScript full calendar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52309207/how-to-use-custom-button-only-for-month-view-in-javascript-full-calendar)

Comment: @Tom 1) that answer is for a much older version of fullCalendar and the same syntax won't work anymore, and 2) it's not doing what the OP asks. They want a button in the header, but that code writes buttons into each of the individual days in the calendar grid. Can you retract the close vote please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can detect when the view has changed, and set the header toolbar option accordingly, to include or exclude your button.

Simple example:

```
    viewDidMount: function (arg) {
      if (arg.view.type == "dayGridMonth") {
        calendar.setOption("headerToolbar", {
          left: "prev,next today myCustomButton",
          center: "title",
          right: "dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay"
        });
      }
      else {
        calendar.setOption("headerToolbar", {
          left: "prev,next today",
          center: "title",
          right: "dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay"
        });
      }
    }
```

Working demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/yLRxger

Relevant documentation:

- https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v5/view-render-hooks
- https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v5/view-object
- https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v5/dynamic-options
- https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v5/customButtons

Answer (score 0):

I found the [viewDidMount](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v5/view-render-hooks) hook useful. Let's do something when the view changes, eg:

```
var calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
customButtons: {
    myCustomButton: {
        text: 'custom!',
        click: function() {
            alert('clicked the custom button!');
        }
    }
},
headerToolbar: {
    left: 'prev,next today myCustomButton',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
},

viewDidMount: function(obj) {
    document.querySelector(".fc-myCustomButton-button").style.display =
        obj.view.type == "dayGridMonth" ? "inline-block" : "none";
},
```

});